# How to control the voltage coming off an AC source?

Tags: arduino, ac, voltage-divider

I need a way to reduce the voltage coming off a [±25 volt square wave AC source](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=LCC25). Hopefully, I can interface this with an arduino.

I'm thinking a simple voltage divider, controlled by a [digital potentiometer.](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10613)  Maybe something like this?

I have two questions:

1. Will this design work? That is, can I feed it a ±25v square wave, and convert that to a ±10v, or ±3.2v square wave? My concern is that the digital potetiometer requires voltage rails as large as the max VAC of my signal.
2. Is there some better way to reduce a square wave with a micro-controller? One problem with my "design" is that it seems like it requires all the power to be consumed inside one of the voltage divider resistors.

[image]

Comment: @RohatKılıç can you elaborate?

Comment: You write square wave digital potentiometer yet the picture shows s sine wave and no digital potentiometer.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to read the ±25V source with your Arduino? You have 50Vpp and need to reduce that to 5Vpp while adding 2.5Vdc offset.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: If that is the requirement, this kind of question is very common and you could do worse than studying Olin Lathrop's answer here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247076/oscillation-in-voltage-rectifier-scaling-circuit/295070#295070

Comment: @replete No, its not about reading. I can read it with a 3 resistor DC-shift like circuit. I gotta control the power source.

Comment: - and by power source, I mean, the ±25V source.

Comment: What at your output specs and can’t you use the programmable interface?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to control the output voltage of the linked [LCC25 driver module](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=LCC25) is to connect it to your Arduino with an RS232 cable and give it commands as [described in the manual of the LCC25 liquid crystal controller.](https://www.thorlabs.com/_sd.cfm?fileName=18828-D02.pdf&partNumber=LCC25)

Your proposed "solution" can change voltage, but only for "loads" whose resistance is many times that of your voltage divider.  You could probably measure the voltage properly with a good multimeter, but you couldn't draw enough current to actually do anything useful with it.

You also have the problem that digital potentiometers can only handle input voltages within their own supply voltage.  So, not going to work if you have +-25V and the potentiometer is running on 5V.

Just use that supply as it is designed.  **Talk** to it over RS232, and **tell** it what you want.

---

I see in the comments to a deleted answer that you need to be able to control it faster, that the USB commands have too much latency.

Controlling it through an Arduino and a digital potentiometer wouldn't be much (if any) faster.

Controlling it through RS232 won't be any faster.

The controller can be programmed to modulate its output.  If you know how it needs to be modulated, then you could set it up beforehand.

If you don't know how you need to modulate it beforehand, then you'll have go another route.

But, there's not enough information in your question or the comments to really explain what needs to be done.

You would need to explain what tells you when you need to change the modulation, and how.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the output current. If this is a control signal and if all you need is just two output levels - clamp it with a bank of zeners!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1sBA7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you need to do that with dual voltages, then add a second set for another polarity and use some optocouplers to drive the transistors.